# How to get input bindings from a resource in another azure resource group?

Tags: azure-functions, serverless, azure-resource-group

I want to explore the possibilities of creating Azure Function Apps for common use-cases. In the tutorials and examples, there is always created a dedicated resource group for the new function app and consequently there are new, explicit resources created. What if I want to create a function app, that needs to get a input binding from a resource of another resource group? How is this realized within the function.json?

Answer (score 1):

An Azure Resource Group is a *logical* grouping of resources within Azure, but has *no functional relevance*. It has nothing to do with accessing resources in other resource groups.

Taken from [Azure Resource Manager overview - Resource groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview#resource-groups):

> There are some important factors to consider when defining your resource group:
>
> - All the resources in your group should share the same lifecycle. You deploy, update, and delete them together. If one resource, such as a database server, needs to exist on a different deployment cycle it should be in another resource group.
> - Each resource can only exist in one resource group.
> - You can add or remove a resource to a resource group at any time.
> - You can move a resource from one resource group to another group. For more information, see Move resources to new resource group or subscription.
> - A resource group can contain resources that are located in different regions.
> - A resource group can be used to scope access control for administrative actions.
> - **A resource can interact with resources in other resource groups.** This interaction is common when the two resources are related but don't share the same lifecycle (for example, web apps connecting to a database).

Triggers & bindings connect to the resources they need by using (for instance) connection strings. This means that, if need be, you would even be able to trigger *your* Function based on an *external* Azure resource, as long as you have the right information and credentials to connect to that resource.

This example in the Azure Serverless Community Library might be helpfull: [Using Triggers & Bindings in Azure Functions](https://serverlesslibrary.net/sample/3780ff19-50f6-4991-9974-368f70402ae5).